# Why are there different colors in several Questions

Tags: discussion

Well I have been noticing there are difference in colors in several questions in Magento SE. Is there any reason for this ? Are there question under some review ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlighted questions are marked with your favorite tags.
If you want to disable them, go to your account, click on edit profile, select the preferences (or [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/41318))  and scroll down to the tags area. Remove all your favorite tags and you are done. No more highlighted questions in the list.

[image: tags]

Comment: Ok. Thats grt. Dint knew about that :p

Comment: hi Marius, please check once your answer. The link which you mentioned in your answer to
> click here
is not found

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara. The link works for the OP and for the admins. If you want your link use `https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/{your-id-goes-here}.`

Comment: yes. its worked with my id. Don't mind sir.
but if you edit answer, thats good to see i think.